# I can’t drag any of the icons in my dock in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, dock, drag-and-drop

I can’t drag any of the icons in my dock. I cannot reorder the icons and I’m also not able to drag the contents of a docked folder that is expanded to trash. The icons react to the drag by opening the application or file.

I don’t know what I did to cause this. Googling didn’t help much and neither has this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock contents-immutable -bool false; killall Dock;
```

Comment: Do you have the `Pushbullet extension` installed for Chrome ?

Comment: Yes I do. Might that be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the [Pushbullet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pushbullet/chlffgpmiacpedhhbkiomidkjlcfhogd) extension installed for Chrome, try to disable the “Universal copy & paste” option and then give your Mac a restart.